# Why is @typescript-eslint/promise-function-async triggered by this code?

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have this code in my little project:

```js
close(flush = false): void {
    if (this.ws?.CLOSING || this.ws?.CLOSED) {
        return;
    }

    if (flush) {
        // I really don't know how to fix that
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/promise-function-async
        const sendPromises = this.state.queue.map((message) =>
            this.sendAsync(message)
        );
        void Promise.all(sendPromises).then(() => this.ws?.close());
    } else {
        this.ws?.close();
    }
}
```

When I run `xo` (which uses typescript-eslint) on it, `@typescript-eslint/promise-function-async` fails. I made a few changes, but it still fails. Can anyone give me an explanation about why this doesn't work?

What I tried:

```js
// first
const sendPromises: Promise<void> = this.state.queue.map((message) => this.sendAsync(message));
// second
const sendPromises = this.state.queue.map((message): Promise<void> => this.sendAsync(message));
```

Comment: Is the problem `@typescript-eslint/promise-function-async` or `@typescript-eslint/restrict-template-expressions`?

Comment: Also, likely the rule wants you to do `this.state.queue.map(async (message) => this.sendAsync(message) );`

Comment: Mark the function that returns a promise as async as the rule requires? Did you read https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/promise-function-async.md?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the description of the [`@typescript-eslint/promise-function-async`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/promise-function-async.md) rule:

> Requires any function or method that returns a Promise to be marked async.

With example for **incorrect** code:

```
const arrowFunctionReturnsPromise = () => Promise.resolve('value');

function functionReturnsPromise() {
  return Promise.resolve('value');
}
```

and **correct** code:

```
const arrowFunctionReturnsPromise = async () => Promise.resolve('value');

async function functionReturnsPromise() {
  return Promise.resolve('value');
}
```

Your code fails the first line of the example. More specifically the problem is here:

```
const sendPromises = this.state.queue.map((message) =>
  this.sendAsync(message)
);
```

You're calling `.map()` with an arrow function that produces a promise, so according to the rule, you have to mark it as `async` like so:

```
const sendPromises = this.state.queue.map(async (message) =>
//                                        ^^^^^
  this.sendAsync(message)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

After I read the comments I noticed that I should add `async` to my arrow function.

Ironically, I fixed the same error before but I overlooked this one.

Thanks for helping.